# Find by document's subobject's value, do not show others

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

First of all please correct the question's title to appropriate one - it was hard for me to find a short and descriptive title to the question below.

Lets say I have a list of documents like ones below:

```
[
    cdate: { $date: ""2015-09-15T05:53:04.656Z" },
    factor1: "aaa",
    factor2: "bbb",
    extra_info: [
        { host: "ex.com", int_value: 10 },
        { host: "ms.com", int_value: 20 },
        { host: "apple.com", int_value: 5 },
        ..
    ]
]
```

`extra_info` array size varies. I need to get **all documents** having **factor1="something"**, **factor2="something else"** and one of **extra_info**'s array's host should be equal to **"ms.com"**. The result should be presented as:

```
[
    cdate: { $date: ""2015-09-15T05:53:04.656Z" },
    factor1: "something",
    factor2: "something else",
    host: "ms.com",
    int_value: 5
],
[
    cdate: { $date: ""2015-09-14T08:17:32.123Z" },
    factor1: "something",
    factor2: "something else",
    host: "ms.com",
    int_value: 14
],
...
```

The question is how to do it?

One ways is that I can get all the documents and then manually filter out **extra_info** array, leaving only values that I need, but is there any way to stick it in under one query?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. You are right. Positional operator is only for updating.

Comment: You can use: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: yes, elemMatch will be used to filter out only documents containing certain `host`, but the result of the query will contain all `extra_info` array anyway, which I then need to look through. This is a two step solution, but the question was is there any clever/geeky way to achieve result? Like using aggregate or map-reduce..